# Generic class input param type miss match

Tags: java, android, kotlin, rx-android

Always get an Error type mismatch, when input param for **getObjectSingle**.
how do I fix with my generic wrapper class?

[image]

[image]

Comment: try Wrapper.class

Comment: can you more detail, please?

Comment: Pass into the getObjectSingle(Wrapper.class)

Comment: still error with balloon message "Function invocation Wrapper<SignInResponse>() expected" ... try like balloon message. same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the class not the instance, but you must create an instance of the class to get class itself, try this:

```
val wrapper = Wrapper<String>()

Rx2AndroidNetworking.post(someUrl)
        .build()
        .getObjectSingle(wrapper.javaClass)
```

OR

```
val wrapper = Wrapper<String>()

Rx2AndroidNetworking.post(someUrl)
        .build()
        .getObjectSingle(wrapper::class.java)
```

OR

```
val wrapper = Wrapper<String>()

val s: Class<Wrapper<String>> = wrapper.javaClass

Rx2AndroidNetworking.post(someUrl)
        .build()
        .getObjectSingle(s)
```

Comment: Wrapper<SignInResponse>().javaClass